# how to define length of slices into array in golang?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have an array of slices and I want to define length of slices, because when I'm trying to launch a code getting the panic:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

the code:

```
func Transpose(m [][]int) [][]int{
    arr := make([][]int, len(m))

    for i:=0; i <len(arr); i++ {
        for j:=0; j<len(arr); j++ {
            arr[j][i] = m[i][j]
        }
    }
    
return arr
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't initialised each inner slice. `arr := make([][]int, len(m))` only initialise the outer loop of the `arr` slice.

```
func Transpose(m [][]int) [][]int {
    arr := make([][]int, len(m))

    for i := 0; i < len(m); i++ {

        arr[i] = make([]int, len(m[i]))

        for j := 0; j < len(m[i]); j++ {
            arr[i][j] = m[j][i]
        }
    }

    return arr
}
```